# Notepad++ - Find duplicate lines by first word

Tags: regex, windows, duplicates, notepad++

I've been searching on the internet to solve my problem and read through several Stack Overflow topics but I can't get it working.

So I have multiple files with translations. Each line contains one translation with a translation key in front of it.
The key is split from the translated phrase with a `:`. There can be multiple underscores in the key but no space. Each key has to be unique even if the translation phrase is different.

This is a small example how these files look:

```
CONFIRM: Conferma
FOR: per
YOU_WILL_RECEIVE: Riceverai
ENCHANTED: Incantato
ITEMS_AVAILABLE: Prodotti disponibili
CONTINUE: Continua
MONEY_PAID: Money Paid
GUI_OVERVIEW_OPENSHOPS_ACTION: Clicca per aprire i negozi
GUI_OVERVIEW_OPENSETTINGS_ACTION: Clicca per aprire le impostazioni
GUI_SHOPSETTINGS_BUY_LEFTACTION: **Tasto Sinistro** per **cambiare** il prezzo d'acquisto
GUI_SHOPSETTINGS_BUY_QACTION: **Premi Q** per disabilitare l'acquisto
ENCHANTED: Incantato premituro
GUI_SHOPSETTINGS_BUY_OTHERACTION: **Clicca** per abilitare l'**acquisto**
```

In this example the `ENCHANTED` key is duplicate even these keys have different translation phrases. I just want to see that this key is duplicated.

My plan is to match all these lines with a regex pattern with the help of notepad++ but if it's easier for you, it would also be okay if I have to use a script. Something like Batch or even a little NodeJS application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In notepad++ you can use this regex to find the *first* occurrence of any key which is duplicated:

```
^(\w+):(?=.*\R\1:)
```

It looks for a sequence of word characters between the start of a line and a `:`, captured in group 1 and then asserts a positive lookahead for the same string starting a line again (`\R` matches a newline/crlf character). Note you need to have the `. matches newline` checkbox selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer. That works pretty well. Any chance this could be extended to also delete all lines but the first match?
I am happy with the matching tho. That helps a ton!

Comment: @Relentless that's a bit trickier... in notepad you could try searching for `^((\w+):.*)\R+\2:[^\r\n]+` and replacing with `\1` but that requires manually clicking `Replace All` a few times in case of overlapping matches.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thanks again!